# NoMethodError on line ["32"] in Rails 3.2 with latest Compass and Sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass, compass-sass

I have been searching around a bit to find a solution to this error message I am getting and based on my research it would appear this error should have been fixed in the latest compass-rails and/or sass-rails gem releases.  However, I am still getting the error message and it is probably because I am missing something silly.

I am getting the error message when running the compass compile command.

The full error message is:

```
NoMethodError on line ["32"] of /home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

My .scss file looks like this:

```
 @import "base";


#container {
   @include background-image(linear-gradient(#CBD7E2, #00AEEF)); 
   @include background-size(auto);

   padding: $container-pad;
}

#header {
   background-image: image-url("logo.gif");
}
```

Logo.gif is located in the rails project directory in app/assets/images.

What am I missing / doing wrong here?  Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks,
Meebix

---

**Update:**  Seems I just needed URL.  I am still not able to get an image to render to the browser however. I have my image in assets/images. I notice that compiling compass doesn't move any images to the public/assets folder (not sure if that is even supposed to happen).

What am I forgetting to do?

Comment: Ugh. I am such a dummy. I figured this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

In my opinion that

```
background-image: image-url("logo.gif");
```

should be

```
background-image: url("logo.gif");
```

Comment: Yup, you were right. I confused myself reading some other tips. If logo.gif is in assets/images, why is the image not rendering with just background-image: url("logo.gif");?

Compiling Compass doesn't move any images to the public folder either (maybe that isn't supposed to happen) - but I can't get an image to render to the browser.

Comment: try background-image: url("images/logo.gif");